Flashing and diagonal browser display after moving pi
I'm having a strange situation whereby any browser opens flashing with a stretched diagonoal display.
Running on Raspbian but unsure the version number.

All I have done since it was last working correctly was unplug and move the pi itself.
What has happened?!

Did you shut the system down properly before unplugging it?

Nah, I pulled the plug. But I've done that a million time before with no adverse side effects haha

If the system is idle it usually won't cause a problem but it isn't a good habit.  Normal computers are less prone to this because they have power buttons that run a shutdown, but it is the same issue.  Anyway, not necessarily the cause.  You might want to make it clear which OS and version you are using and when you ran the last update.

Running on Raspbian, but not sure which version it was... Definitely not the latest.

Only "any browser" is effected like this? Which model pi? What is the output of lsb_release -a (this will narrow down the version of the OS)

refresh the web page

@JaromandaX No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release: 12
Codename: bookworm

@jsotola it literally happens when opening a web browser
